# count words of text file in python3

Tags: python

I am learning python and I want to create a program which counts total number of words from textfile.

```py
fname = input("Enter file name: ") 
with open(fname,'r') as hand:
     for line in hand:
         lin = line.rstrip()
         wds = line.split()
         print(wds)
     wordCount = len(wds)
     print(wordCount)
```

**Contents of my text file is:**
Hello this is my test program
I am new to python
Thank you

---

When I print `wds` after splitting. 
I get the splited text from textfile, but when I tried to print the length, I just get the length of last word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `wordCount = 0` and then inside the `for loop` you need to add to wordCount every time you iterate. Something like this:

```
wordCount = 0
for line in hand:
    lin = line.rstrip()
    wds = lin.split()
    print(wds)
    wordCount += len(wds)
print(wordCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four things to be done:

- open a file
- read lines from the file
- read words from the lines
- print the number of words

So, simply do that, in that order ;)

```
with open(fname,'r') as f:
    words = [word for line in f
             for word in line.strip().split()]
print(f"Number of words: {len(words)}")
```